# Adding (cifs, samba)Filesystem resource to PCS

Tags: mount, samba, pacemaker, corosync, pcs

I am trying to create *PCS* resource *Filesystem* on Samba share(cifs) file system type.

Here is a command that I have used to create pcs resource.

```
root@shaunak-VirtualBox:~# pcs resource show SMBDiskResourceName
 Resource: SMBDiskResourceName (class=ocf provider=heartbeat type=Filesystem)
  Attributes: device=//192.168.1.6/my_data_share directory=/var/opt/my/data fstype=cifs options="vers=3.0,username=myuser,password=myuser,uid= 998,gid=998,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777"
```

Here is a error I am getting while starting resource,

```
root@shaunak-VirtualBox:~# pcs resource debug-start SMBDiskResourceName
Error performing operation: Operation not permitted
Operation start for SMBDiskResourceName (ocf:heartbeat:Filesystem) returned 1
 >  stderr: INFO: Running start for //192.168.1.6/mssql_data_share on /var/opt/mssql/data
 >  stderr: 
 >  stderr: Usage:
 >  stderr:  mount [-lhV]
 >  stderr:  mount -a [options]
 >  stderr:  mount [options] [--source] <source> | [--target] <directory>
 >  stderr:  mount [options] <source> <directory>
 >  stderr:  mount <operation> <mountpoint> [<target>]
 >  stderr: 
 >  stderr: Mount a filesystem.
 >  stderr: 
.....
 >  stderr: 
 >  stderr: For more details see mount(8).
 >  stderr: ocf-exit-reason:Couldn't mount filesystem //192.168.1.6/my_data_share on /var/opt/my/data
```

Above error says, mount is not happening on `/192.168.1.6/my_data_share` but where I run mount command, I am able to do mounting.

Note sure what I am missing here. Here is a my mount command which I executed successfully.

```
mount -t  cifs //192.168.1.6/my_data_share /var/opt/my/data -o vers=3.0,username=myuser,password=myuser,uid=998,gid=998,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```